# How do you serialize a Spring Bean (spring 3)

Tags: spring, serialization

I understand this is supposed to happen automatically, but it's doing anything but in my experience. Does anyone know how to serialize a Bean which has indirect/direct references to other non-serializable Beans/classes?

Comment: Ooooooohhh! Yes yes, I was looking at that question for a long time and just didn't realize that they need the scope=session addition to the annotation. That must be my mistake. You should copy that into the answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only session scoped beans are serialized automatically. There's a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180963/spring-session-scoped-beans-controllers-and-references-to-services-in-terms-of). So, all credits to Hans Westerbeek.