# JSF 2 viewScope bean with transient injected Spring service bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

All

I am using JSF2 2.1.4 and Spring 3.1.0. I have @ViewScoped managed bean which is Serializable. It has dependencies to few Spring @Service beans which in turn have dependencies. I followed this [Spring session-scoped beans (controllers) and references to services, in terms of serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180963/spring-session-scoped-beans-controllers-and-references-to-services-in-terms-o)

There people have found solution by linking post to a video, but still I am not able to get, shall I make my services transient and after deserialization things will be taken care of or I have to make all services hence repositories and so on... serializable.

I'll appreciate if someone helps with this, I am bit confused. Currently I have made @Service dependencies transient, if I don't, it complains dependencies are not serializable.

Thanks ......

Comment: If you have a question about an answer on Stackoverflow, you might try leaving a comment on that answer, or setting a bounty. Since you have insuffient reputation to do the latter (and I am interested too), I have done that for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring session-scoped beans (controllers) and references to services, in terms of serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180963/spring-session-scoped-beans-controllers-and-references-to-services-in-terms-o)

Answer (score 1):

All

Waited for few days for some one to respond .. :)
Well I was aware of following solution [Porting JSF 2.0′s ViewScope to Spring 3.0](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/) but was waiting for someone with another solution beside this. Above link works for me hope it helps someone.

Comment: Doesn't the view scope require the bean to be serializable? What did you do about the non-serializable dependencies?

Comment: Well yes, just tweak private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) and private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) in view scoped bean according to needs i.e. rebuild properties which are transient.

Comment: I see. Did you do that using ApplicationContext.getBean() or did you find a better method?

Comment: Yes, the same but this process can be definitely made automated by scanning for specific annotated properties and injecting back.