# Spring3 deserialization - singleton injection

Tags: spring, jsf

i am developing a Webapplication with JSF2 and Spring3 and have a problem with deserialization.

I have some session-scoped beans defined like so:

```
@Controller(value = "admin")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class AdminBean implements Serializable {
...
```

also i have some singletons defined like so:

```
@Repository
public class Repo {
```

Singletons are injected into the session-beans like this

```
@Resource
private transient Repo repo;
```

After i added `transient`, my problems with serialization/deserialization went away. But now i have the problem that after deserialzing the dependencies (`repo` in this case) are null. I searched a lot on this problem and found some workarounds, but i still wonder what the best solution for this problem is?

It seems to me that using application-scoped beans in session-beans is a quite common case, isn't there a clean solution for this? I came arround a solution with @Configurable, but do i really need some load-time-weaving stuff? The targets of the injection are already spring-managed, so it doesn't make sense to me..
Please enlight me

*update 2 years later*: You CAN transparently inject session-scoped beans into application-scoped-beans (might not be a good idea in most cases though). I just had to set the proxyMode on @Scope accordingly.

Comment: Wow. EJB3 handles this transparently. I'd expect Spring to do it as well. Is there any particular reason that you're using Spring these days, with Java EE 6?

Comment: @BalusC He may be using it for loads of integration modules with external libraries, testing capabilities or just because he uses Spring MVC (there's no such thing like JEE6MVC) or hundreds of other reasons. Don't start ideological or religius debates.

Comment: @Peter: I was just curious because I have never used Spring and try to understand the reasons people have to use it (by the way, using Spring MVC together with JSF would be contradictory).

Comment: It's just the whole package with transactions, aop ,testing and the fact that i can run on a lightweight servlet-container with startup time under 10seconds that makes Spring more attractive than EJB for me. For web applications i still don't see what gain i would have with EJB3

Comment: Do you really intend to use session serialization? In many cases it's not necessary and you can safely disable it in your container.

Comment: It is absolutely not nessesary and i am certain i will disable session serialization in context.xml for this project. Still, i am curious and would really like to find out how to do this for future projects.

Comment: Can you give a case for needing singleton injection let alone singletons?  Nearly every case where a singleton is used, the situation didn't call for it, thus it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @maple_shaft I'm curious: how do you define and inject your DataSource in spring applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` through `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()` and there are some methods like `autowireBeanProperties`, `autowireBean` and `configureBean` that should be able to reconfigure your ban after deserialization. Choose a method best for you (one of them triggers post processing, others not etc..)

Second idea is to wrap `Repo` in a proxy, that is serializable. It'll serialize with `AdminBean` and deserialize. This proxy should hold 'real' transient reference and if it gets null after deserialization, it should lookup it from the Application Context.

I heard that Spring 3 automaticaly wraps beans with such a proxy, but I've never managed to make it work.

Comment: **Spring3 automaticaly wraps with proxy:** i can't get that to work either, i think that there should be some "spring-magic" for this, because it seems to be a fairly common case

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem using @ViewScoped of JSF where backing bean has to serializable which in turn wants all dependencies to be serializable, which in all scenarios is not possible to get all. As @Peter mentioned about Spring 3 have a look at link @ stackoverflow discussing same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180963/spring-session-scoped-beans-controllers-and-references-to-services-in-terms-o). I used transient for some dependencies(Spring) and for deserialization process I hooked bean to

`private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
 and private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)`

in view scoped bean and tweaked them to get proper reference.