# JSF ManagedBean - injected properties not working correctly on STATE_SAVING_METHOD=client

Tags: spring, jsf, viewstate, mybatis, managed-bean

I am into a problem from two days and I can not get out from this.

The problem I am having is using a MangedBean property after the deserialization (I guess).
The property (purchaseManager) is set up with Spring, and use a DAO which extends MyBatis as data mapper to interact with the DB.
In fact, on the first access to the page, purchaseManager.getAll() inside init() method works fine.
When i try to call refreshList() as an action from a button, I have a NullPointerException on the getSqlSession() inside the DAO.

Letting only the relevant code the situation is as follow:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "purchaseController")
@ViewScoped
public class PurchaseController implements Serializable{

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{purchaseManager}")
    private PurchaseManager purchaseManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        purchaseManager.getAll();
    }

    public void refreshList(){
        purchaseManager.getAll();
    }
}

public class PurchaseManagerImpl implements PurchaseManager, Serializable {
    PurchaseDAO purchaseDAO;

    public void getAll() {
        purchaseDAO.getAll()
    }
}

public class PurchaseDAOImpl extends SqlSessionDaoSupport implements PurchaseDAO, Serializable {

    public void getAll() {
        SqlSession session = getSqlSession();  // when the call comes from refreshList(), session is null
        session.selectList("PAYMENT.getAll", null);
    }
}

in web.xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If I change the STATE_SAVING_METHOD to server the application works fine but is not what I want. Same thing if I make the ManageBean as RequestScope but this too will penalize my requirements.

Thank you in advance to anyone for any kind of help!
Ermal

Comment: I don't do Spring, so I may be completely wrong, but why are you attempting to inject a Spring managed bean as a JSF managed property? I have never seen this. Spring has its own annotations for this.

Comment: In Spring infrastructure I have the logic (DAOs and Services) which is an own project BL used by two other web applications, Front-End and Admin-Tool. A lot of references shows this way of injecting ManagedBeans as property of other managed bean. Here an example: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Yes, I know how injecting JSF managed beans work, but you're treating a Spring managed bean as a JSF managed bean. If it were an EJB (which Spring is supposed to supplant), you would have used `@EJB` instead of `@ManagedProperty` which will basically inject a fully serializable proxy instance. Does Spring really not have some annotation for that? `@Autowired` or so?

Comment: `@Autowired` seems to be the solution to inject correctly the spring beans. 
Although, I have the error _**com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: 
An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean purchaseController**_ in the PurchaseController.init() method. 
My applications seems stabile only when using `@ManagedProperty`. 
From your experience, what may cause an eventual issue in PRD environment with only `@ManagedProperty`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BalusC. Starting from your observation I solved the problem adding `<aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" /> ` in the Spring bean definition.
Now that my manager/service object is defined as I said, thing are working fine. So my DB (MyBatis) reference is not null anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the error adding `<aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />` to the definition of the service/manager declared through Spring. This makes possible the injection of a fully serializable proxy instance.

```
<bean id="purchaseManager" class="al.ozone.bl.manager.impl.PurchaseManagerImpl">    
    <property name="purchaseDAO" ref="purchaseDAO" />   
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>
```

`proxy-target-class="false"` is for telling that `PurchaseManagerImpl` implements already an interface. If setted to `true` or omitted, CGLIB2 library must be used.

In this way JSF is correctly taking data from DB using Spring+MyBatis.

The mistery (for me) on this point (more theorical) is :

- Is MyBatis object (`PurchaseDAOImpl`) and the `dataSource`, correctly handled behind the scenes?
- Are they recreated or restored on each HTTP request?

Remember that I have `STATE_SAVING_METHOD=client` and BackingBean as `ViewScope`. 
My Goal is to have the server lighter possible because I expect an hight number of user interactions.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Thank you very much to anyone for some light on this matter!

Consulted links:

[Spring session-scoped beans (controllers) and references to services, in terms of serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180963/spring-session-scoped-beans-controllers-and-references-to-services-in-terms-o)

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Whats-New-in-Spring-3.0

Comment: <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" /> solved this error. Setting this question as accepted, maybe helping other people with same issue.