# Clean way to wire variables after serialization?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, serialization, zk

I've got a web application ( tomcat 7, spring 4.2, ZK 7). As I have two servers that can "take over" the other's sessions, serialization of the sessions is required, which leads to the problem that I have to somehow re-initialize the spring services after deserialization. Due to the structure of ZK, it is required that the `Composers` (kind of Controllers) need to be serialized (and these Composers use Services).

For example, let's say I have an object that needs to be serialized. This objects has a reference to a Spring service (which cannot be serialized, since in the end, there's a reference to a `DataSource`, `SqlSessionTemplate`, etc. - all of them not `Serializable`).

So, now how to solve this problem elegantly? Is there some way to integrate Spring into the deserialization process so that Spring automatically re-wires my (transient, autowired) variables after (or even while) deserialization?

The current solution is to have a singleton bean lying around that has a `@Autowired` reference to the ApplicationContext, so that I can access it via getInstance() to get a reference to a Service, but this solution is not very elegant and also makes testing more complex (since I prefer to unit test without loading a Spring context).

Is there some other, preferably better, way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the most obvious and elegant answer is to declare the ScopedProxyMode of a bean, that wraps it into a Proxy and dynamically sets the non-serializable dependencies, for example...

```
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

More can be found in the Spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection). This also has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180963/spring-session-scoped-beans-controllers-and-references-to-services-in-terms-o) on StackOverflow already (with a link to the presentation when they announced it).